# loop in a bindingsource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was wondering if there is a way to loop in a related binding source and not to the actual data shown in DataGrid. the question is asked because in the DataGrid are only data to be shown but in the binding source can be hidden data as well, a flag for example.

When I loop at the binding source though I need to know where am I in the data grid as well (in which row). is this possible? is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: is this WindowsForms or WPF ?

Answer (score 2):

to know in which row you are

```
 int position = bindingsource.Position ;
```

if your binding source is of type Person ..
and you want to select row

```
> var obj = bindingsource.List.OfType<Person>().ToList().Find(p=>p.name==" A name");

 var pos = bindingsource.IndexOf(obj); bindingsource.Position = pos;
```